# How to dotfill the tcolorbox blank

Tags: tcolorbox, fill

The first tcolorbox is the sample example having solution. The last three tcolorboxes contain the problems without solutions, having dot lines. All tcolorboxes are the same height and BREAKABLE.
Please help me correct my code to automatically!
Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=2,
        raster height=\textheight,
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\fontfamily{qag}\textbf{Example 1.}}]
            \lipsum[10]
        \end{tcolorbox}
         \begin{tcolorbox}{\fontfamily{qag}\textbf{Example 2.}} \par
                 \edef\sodongt{\the\numexpr\dimexpr (\tcbtextheight)/(\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax) \relax\relax}
                  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sodong}{int(\sodongt-1)}
                  \foreach \i in {1,...,\sodong}{
                    \dotfill\endgraf
                  }
                \end{tcolorbox}     
               \begin{tcolorbox}
                \edef\sodongt{\the\numexpr\dimexpr (\tcbtextheight)/(\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax) \relax\relax}
                          \pgfmathsetmacro{\sodong}{int(\sodongt-1)}
               {\fontfamily{qag}\textbf{Example 3.}} \par Some text\\
               Some text \sodong
               \foreach \i in {1,...,\sodong}{
                            \dotfill\endgraf
                          }        
               \end{tcolorbox}
               \begin{tcolorbox}
               \edef\sodongt{\the\numexpr\dimexpr (\tcbtextheight)/(\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax) \relax\relax}
                                  \pgfmathsetmacro{\sodong}{int(\sodongt-1)}
                       {\fontfamily{qag}\textbf{Example 4.}} \par Some text\\
                       Some text 2\\
                        Some text 3\\
                       \foreach \i in {1,...,\sodong}{
                                    \dotfill\endgraf
                                  }           
               \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]